# How can we check that a node B can be visited from a node A so that we can return again to A in mixed graph (Having both direct and undirect edges)?

Tags: graph-theory

We are given a mixed graph (having both type of edges) and we are asked to find no of vertices such as we can traverse from a vertex (let A) to a vertex (let B, connected to A) and can return again to the previous vertex (A) from any path.

Which approach should I use here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the graph is unweighted and by storing the predecessor/parent note at every BFS traversal, we will be getting the shortest path to the dest vertex.

So just run BFS starting at vertex A to get the path until B.

Since your graph contains directed link as well the path from A-> B might not be the same as the path B->A, so we again do a BFS with vertex B as source to get a back to A.